# How to assign a role when a user joins the server?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So, when a user joins my server, I want it to automatically assign the role "ew". How could I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This following code should:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
   guildMember.addRole(guildMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "ew"));
});
```

(Not able to test right now).

Answer (score -1):

```
client.on('serverNewMember', function(server, user) {
     user.addTo(server.roles.get("name", "ew"));
});
```

Note: your client object might not be called `client`, it depends what you name it.

Basically, the client object has an event called `serverNewMember` which is called whenever a new user joins the server. The event supplies the server and user objects. Inside the event function, I used the `addTo` function of `user` to give them the role `ew`.

Comment: I created an alt account and joined the server, however, their role remained @everyone and did not switch to "ew" and no errors were reported in the console. Why was this?

Comment: I'm not sure but client.on('serverNewMember') is not something on Discord.JS library. Might be other library.